# Sharepoint: List - Hide Quick Launch?

Tags: sharepoint, list, hide, quicklaunch

In Sharepoint 2007, how do I hide the Quick Launch bar for all pages in a List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct and automatic method for hiding the Quick Launch only for a specific list. However, we can take two things into account.

1. Application pages, such as List Settings, do not show the Quick Launch by default.
2. [This link](http://blogs.technet.com/collaboration/archive/2008/09/26/how-to-hide-the-quick-launch.aspx) provides a simple script, which I've copied at the end of this answer due to formatting reasons, that can be inserted into a Content Editor Web Part on a non-application page to hide the Quick Launch.

So to accomplish hiding the Quick Launch for a specific list, we'll basically have to visit every non-application-page for that list, and insert this Content Editor Web Part. Primarily, this will only be the separate Views on that list. Go through each view on the list, and using "Edit Page" from the Site Actions, add the CEWP and the script. This should work for all of the list-specific pages which have the Quick Launch. There is a way to slightly automate this process, especially for views, but that requires the object model and I am unsure you wish to go delving into the deeper programming for this task.

Here is the script, for convenience.

```
<style>
    .ms-quicklaunch
    { 
        display:none;
    }
    .ms-navframe
    { 
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```